# checking null with OR in if condition in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using the below query. Instead of using OR condition for every column, do we have any function or any other method to reduce the process time?

A to P is the few columns in the table. If any of the column having null, I need to raise an exception. Else normal flow will continue.

```
cursor ABC is 
select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P 
from table; 
begin 
   FOR rec IN ABC loop begin 
      IF (A IS NULL) OR (B IS NULL) OR (C IS NULL) OR (D IS NULL) OR (E IS NULL) OR (F IS NULL) OR (G IS NULL) OR (H IS NULL) OR (I IS NULL) OR (J IS NULL) OR (K IS NULL) OR (L IS NULL) OR (M IS NULL) OR (N IS NULL) OR (O IS NULL) OR (P IS NULL) 
      THEN 
          RAISE EXCEPTION; 
      ELSE 
          -- PROCESS FLOW 
      END IF; 
      exception 
      end; 
    end loop; 
end;
```

Please help on the above.

Comment: You say "for every column" which implies that we're talking about a SQL statement but you've posted a PL/SQL snippet.  Why do you believe that a series of OR conditions is causing a performance issue?  Could you declare your variables as `not null` and let Oracle raise an exception automatically if you assign them a null value?  I'm not sure that would be meaningfully more efficient though it would eliminate the need to code the `if` statement.

Comment: Hi Justin,Sorry, Forget to mention this is a plsql block. This is a statement inside a cursor. I will pass one value to one column and check the above condition. I'm asking whether this OR condition will impact the performance or not, because around 3 million records I need to process

Comment: I assume you mean a "statement inside a loop" rather than "inside a cursor".  If you are worried about performance, don't do row-by-row processing in the first place, work in sets.  You could likely use declarative `not null` constraints somewhere in the processing as well but from a performance standpoint the major source of slowness will be the row-by-row processing.

Comment: Can you please show your real statement, otherwise it will be difficult to determine if there is any impact. In case you have a `SELECT` from table you may have a performance issue, however not due to `OR` but due to `IS NULL` conditions. NULL values are not covered by an index (by default) and Oracle makes a full table scan.

Comment: Yes Justin, Inside a cursor, inside a loop

Comment: cursor ABC is
select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P from table;

begin
FOR rec IN ABC
loop
begin
IF (A IS NULL) OR (B IS NULL) OR (C IS NULL) OR 
   (D IS NULL) OR (E IS NULL) OR (F IS NULL) OR 
   (G IS NULL) OR (H IS NULL) OR (I IS NULL) OR 
   (J IS NULL) OR (K IS NULL) OR (L IS NULL) OR 
   (M IS NULL) OR (N IS NULL) OR (O IS NULL) OR 
   (P IS NULL) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION;
ELSE
   -- PROCESS FLOW
END IF;
exception
end;
end loop;
end;

Comment: As suspected by Justin Cave the performance issue is driven by the row-by-row processing rather than the `... IS NULL OR ...` structure.

Comment: ok thanks for your replies. Will check and update if any issues comes.